# Sequentially apply multiple functions to object using different lenses

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, lenses

I would like to perform some updates to an array in an object, and then calculate another parameter based on this update. This is what I tried:

```js
import * as R from 'ramda'

const obj = {
    arr: [
        2,
        3
    ],
    result: {
        sumOfDoubled: 0
    }
};

const double = a => {
    return a*2;
}

const arrLens = R.lensProp('arr');
const res0sumOfDblLens = R.lensPath(['result','sumOfDoubled']);

const calc = R.pipe(
    R.over(arrLens,R.map(double)),
    R.view(arrLens),
    R.sum,
    R.set(res0sumOfDblLens)
);

const updatedObjA = calc(obj);
const updatedObjB = R.set(res0sumOfDblLens,R.sum(R.view(arrLens,R.over(arrLens,R.map(double),obj))),obj);


// what I want: {"arr":[4,6],"result":{"sumOfDoubled":10}}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); //{"arr":[2,3],"result":{"sumOfDoubled":0}}, as expected
console.log(JSON.stringify(updatedObjA)); //undefined
console.log(JSON.stringify(updatedObjB)); //{"arr":[2,3],"result":{"sumOfDoubled":10}}, correct result but the array did not update
```

I realise that neither approaches will work; approach A boils down to `R.set(res0sumOfDblLens,10)`, which makes no sense as it doesn't have a target object for the operation. Approach B, on the other hand, manipulates the base object twice rather than passing the result of the first manipulation as an input for the second.

How can I achieve this using only one function composition; i.e. apply the `double()` function to one part of the object, and then passing that updated object as input for calculating `sumOfDoubled`?

Comment: Whenever you use `R.view` you perfom a get operation and lose the context, i.e. the `Object` in your case. I am not familiar with Ramda's optic but AFAIK you just need `R.view` to calc the sum of the nested array outside the `Object` and then `R.set` to set the sum inside the `Object`. The way you use the functional optic resembles the use of normal getters and setters but lenses are both at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as OriDrori's [`converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) solution, you could also use either of two other Ramda functions.  I always prefer [`lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) to `converge` when it works; it feels more like standard FP, where `converge` is very much a Ramda artifact.  It doesn't always do the job because of some of the variadic features of `converge`.  But it does here, and you could write:

```js
const calc = pipe (
  over (arrLens, map (multiply (2))),
  lift (set (res0sumOfDblLens) ) ( 
    pipe (view (arrLens), sum),
    identity
  )
)
```

But that [`identity`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#identity) in either of these solutions makes me wonder if there's something better.  And there is.  Ramda's [`chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) when applied to functions is what's sometimes known as the starling combinator, `:: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`.  Or said a different way, `chain (f, g) //~> (x) => f (g (x)) (x)`.  And that's just what we want to apply here.  So with `chain`, this is simplified further:

```js
const arrLens = lensProp('arr')
const res0sumOfDblLens = lensPath(['result', 'sumOfDoubled'])

const calc = pipe (
  over (arrLens, map (multiply (2))),
  chain (
    set (res0sumOfDblLens), 
    pipe (view (arrLens), sum)
  )
) 

const obj = { arr: [2, 3], result: { sumOfDoubled: 0 }}

console .log (calc (obj))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {lensProp, lensPath, pipe, over, map, multiply, chain, set, view, sum} = R </script>
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: You specified the type signature of the applicative functor. The monadic one is `(a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a) -> b -> c`. Actually you can use `ap` here since the chained computation doesn't depend on the previous value.

Comment: @bob: well substituting `ap` for `chain` does not work properly.  Maybe Ramda gets this wrong, but `ap (f, g) //~> (x) => f (x) (g(x))`, where `chain (f, g) //~> (x) => f (g (x)) (x)`.

Comment: If we replace `chain` with the corresponding lambda `o => set(res0sumOfDblLens) (pipe(view(arrLens), sum) (o)) (o)` and this in turn with the lambda in applicative style `o => set(res0sumOfDblLens) (o) (pipe(view(arrLens), sum) (o))` it is obvious, that `set` doesn't work properly with its arguments flipped. Hence we need to apply `flip` so that it gets `o => flip(set(res0sumOfDblLens)) (o) (pipe(view(arrLens), sum) (o))`.

Comment: So let's stick with `chain` for convenience :D Sorry for bringing it up in the first place..

Comment: @bob: I started to do that in my previous comment and decided it wasn't worth it.  I still have some issues with `ap` vs `chain` in a function context, and this actually helped me figure it out... so thanks!

Comment: That's good to know. I thought of chain as Ramda's `flatMap`, what's the logic behind giving it a 2nd capacity (starling combinator)?

Comment: @OriDrori: Just as Ramda's `map` extends beyond simply arrays to any [Functor](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor) type, `chain` works with any [Chain](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain) type.  Ramda supplies implementations of `map` for `Array`, `Object`, and `Function`, and delegates to your `map` for other types.  Similarly, Ramda supplies implementations of `chain` for `Array` and `Function`, also delegating.  That this is the starling combinator is not particularly the goal; it's simply the reasonable `chain` for `Function`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the updated value, and the object, so you can set the new sum, you can use `R.converge()`:

```js
const arrLens = R.lensProp('arr');
const res0sumOfDblLens = R.lensPath(['result', 'sumOfDoubled']);

const calc = R.pipe(
  R.over(arrLens, R.map(R.multiply(2))),
  R.converge(R.set(res0sumOfDblLens), [
    R.pipe(R.view(arrLens), R.sum), 
    R.identity
  ])
);

const obj = { arr: [2, 3], result: { sumOfDoubled: 0 }};

const result = calc(obj);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm also using such a pattern `converge` and `identity` to get a reference on an object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a variant without a lense would be a better fit for your case?

```js
const doubleArr = pipe(
    path(['arr']),
    map(x => x*2)
  )
const newData = applySpec({
  arr: doubleArr,
  result: {
    sumOfDoubled: pipe(
       doubleArr,
       sum
    )
  }
})
```